# Angular directive $watch repeated items

Tags: angularjs, service, nested, directive, watch

I am attempting to display two lists.  The first is a loop over an array of objects.  Adding and removing items from that array works as planned.  The nested list pulls data from a factory, which is attached to each item in the first loop, and filters it based on an ID in the original loop.

I am unable to get the $watch function to trigger on the nested elements.  Is there something that I'm missing?  Is there another approach that would be better in terms of Angular best practices?

```js
app.directive('relatedItems', function ($compile) {
return {

      restrict: "E",
      replace: true,
      scope: {
          variations: '='
      },
      template: "<ul><variation-item ng-repeat='variation in variations' variation='variation'></variation-item></ul>",


  }
})

app.directive('variationItem', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace:true,
        scope: {
            variation: '=',
        },
        template: '<li ng-repeat="actor in actors"></li>',

        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('variation.play.actors', function(){
                scope.actors = [];
                for(index in scope.variation.play.actors){
                    if(index.endsWith(\"-Var\" + scope.variation.id)){
                        scope.actors.push(scope.variation.play.actors[index]);
                    }
                }
            });


        }
    }
})
```

Comment: What does your model look like,  I don't see where you are gonna get actors?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/G8KTSR5384hIMJApK2nB?p=preview - is this even close?

Comment: I opted to pass in an already-filtered actors object, which is responding to changes in the data structure in the dom as expected.  Thanks for the effort.